# LSI SAS controller w/ Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, pci

I can't figure out how to get a LSI 9212-4i (SAS2008 chipset) card to work on Ubuntu server 20.04.

I managed to install and load the megaraid modules, but the board still shows up as UNCLAIMED.

Somewhere else I found reference to a **mrsas** module, but I don't have it installed and I don't understand how to load it in my system.

lsmod and lshw outputs below.

Thanks for helping. I'm a bit out of my confort zone.

```
: lsmod | grep mega

megaraid               45056  0
megaraid_sas          163840  0


: lshw
        *-sas UNCLAIMED
             description: Serial Attached SCSI controller
             product: SAS2008 PCI-Express Fusion-MPT SAS-2 [Falcon]
             vendor: Broadcom / LSI
             physical id: 5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:05.0
             version: 03
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: sas cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: ioport:2100(size=256) memory:c0050000-c0053fff memory:c0                                                                       080000-c00bffff memory:c0100000-c017ffff
```

Comment: The 10.04 release is EoL. Install a supported release.

Comment: Can you confirm your version number? Are you really running 10.04?

Comment: Apologies: it's 20.04 - I edited the Question

Comment: Does the HBA show up during BIOS boot (before bootloader and OS boot) so you can hit ctrl-c and check its health, configure its devices etc?

Comment: The HBA is actually a passthrough to a TrueNAS/bhyve VM. I can see the adapter and disks correctly on TrueNAS and I can see the PCI device in the Ubuntu VM. BTW, the adapter is not RAID (IT firmware)